# How to query secondary replicas in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, replicaset

As per this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/distribute-data-globally, each partition consists of four replicas for high availability.

Also, I understand that Stored procedures always run against the primary replica (where all writes go).

When we use DocumentClient to issue client side queries, there are options to set to query across specific regions. But I am not able to find how to query the secondary replicas.

Comment: You don't query the secondary replicas. CosmosDB does this for you. You can however provide the `ConsistencyLevel` as part of you `DocumentClient` initialisation which will affect the replica querying

Comment: @NickChapsas Do the queries from Stored procedures also hit the secondary or just the queries from the client side?

Comment: I don't think it is done on the client side but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

> How to query secondary replicas in Azure Cosmos DB

You may could get the answer from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq).

> Azure Cosmos DB provides global distribution out of the box for availability and low latency reasons. **You do not need to setup replicas etc.** All writes are always durably quorum committed in a any region where you write while providing performance guarantees.